# Why od is not ordering bytes correctly?

Tags: byte

Here's the output dumped from `od -cx`(on linux you can reproduce with `echo -ne "\r\n\n" |od -cx`):

```
0000000  \r  \n  \n  \0
        0a0d 000a
0000003
```

The correct first 2 bytes should be `0d0a` but it outputs `0a0d`,why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you're on a little-endian system? a 16-bit integer will be the high byte followed by the low byte; in this case the 2nd byte followed by the first.

Comment: little endian has nothing to do with a ascii string,it only affects multibyte characters,right?

Comment: it affects any multibyte unit, and the -x switch causes od to dump 16-bit units in hexadecimal. you notice it's dumping the ASCII in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Because your computer is using the so-called ["little-endian"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_endian) method to represent words in the memory (the x86 processor architecture is a common example of little endian systems).

Answer (score 0):

Because it's reading it as shorts and not as bytes. Short is 2 bytes reversed.